# Persist data with related entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have a Budget form that lists data from Client entity in a `select` field. Summarizing, Budget and Client are related to each other. Budget has `client_id` column, that is suppose to store it by getting the `id` value from the selected Client.

```
<form action="{{ path('panel_add_budget') }}" method="POST">
    <strong>Cliente</strong>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="cdg_budget_type[client_id]" class="form-control">
            {% for client in clients %}
                <option value="{{ client.id }}">{{ client.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.address) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.installments) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.check_days) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.date_start) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.total_value) }}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

My Client entity:

```
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $streetName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $district;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $zipCode;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $budget;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set streetName
     *
     * @param string $streetName
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setStreetName($streetName)
    {
        $this->streetName = $streetName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get streetName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStreetName()
    {
        return $this->streetName;
    }

    /**
     * Set district
     *
     * @param string $district
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setDistrict($district)
    {
        $this->district = $district;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get district
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDistrict()
    {
        return $this->district;
    }

    /**
     * Set number
     *
     * @param string $number
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get number
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set zipCode
     *
     * @param string $zipCode
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setZipCode($zipCode)
    {
        $this->zipCode = $zipCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zipCode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getZipCode()
    {
        return $this->zipCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set budget
     * 
     * @param integer $budget
     */
    function setBudget($budget)
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;
    }

    /**
     * Get budget
     * 
     * @return integer
     */
    function getBudget()
    {
        return $this->budget;
    }
}
```

Budget entity:

```
class Budget
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $clientId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $installments;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $checkDays;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dateStart;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     */
    private $totalValue;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set clientId
     *
     * @param integer $clientId
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setClientId($clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clientId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->clientId;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set installments
     *
     * @param integer $installments
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setInstallments($installments)
    {
        $this->installments = $installments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get installments
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getInstallments()
    {
        return $this->installments;
    }

    /**
     * Set checkDays
     *
     * @param integer $checkDays
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCheckDays($checkDays)
    {
        $this->checkDays = $checkDays;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get checkDays
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCheckDays()
    {
        return $this->checkDays;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateStart
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateStart
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setDateStart($dateStart)
    {
        $this->dateStart = $dateStart;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateStart
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateStart()
    {
        return $this->dateStart;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalValue
     *
     * @param decimal $totalValue
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setTotalValue($totalValue)
    {
        $this->totalValue = $totalValue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalValue
     *
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function getTotalValue()
    {
        return $this->totalValue;
    }
}
```

My oneToMany relationship of Client with Budget:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Client:
    type: entity
    table: client
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\ClientRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        phone:
            type: string
            length: 255
        email:
            type: string
            length: 255
        streetName:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: street_name
        district:
            type: string
            length: 255
        number:
            type: string
            length: 255
        city:
            type: string
            length: 255
        zipCode:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: zip_code
    oneToMany:
        budget:
            targetEntity: Budget
            mappedBy: clientId
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And my manyToOne relation of Budget with Client:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget:
    type: entity
    table: budget
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\BudgetRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        address:
            type: string
            length: 255
        installments:
            type: integer
        checkDays:
            type: integer
            column: check_days
        dateStart:
            type: datetime
            column: date_start
        dateCreated:
            type: datetime
            column: date_created
        totalValue:
            type: decimal
            column: total_value
            nullable: true
    manyToOne:
        clientId:
            targetEntity: Client
            inversedBy: budget
            joinColumn:
                name: client_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

To finish, my `addAction`, from `BudgetController`:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType());

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $manager->persist($form->getData());
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:Budget:add.html.twig', array(
        'clients' => $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Client')->findAll(),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

When submitting the form, an exception is thrown:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

```
public function getEntityState($entity, $assume = null)
{
    $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);
    if (isset($this->entityStates[$oid])) {
        return $this->entityStates[$oid];
```

Its Stack Trace:

```
at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('2', 'spl_object_hash() expects    parameter 1 to be object, integer given', '/home/gabriel/Documents/CasaDoGesso/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php', '1389',   array('entity' => '2', 'assume' => '2'))
at spl_object_hash ('2')
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 1389  +
at UnitOfWork ->getEntityState ('2', '2')
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 788  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeAssociationChanges (array('fieldName' =>    'clientId', 'targetEntity' => 'CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Client', 'inversedBy' => 'budget', 'joinColumns' => array(array('referencedColumnName' => 'id', 'name' => 'client_id')), 'type' => '2', 'mappedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => true, 'sourceEntity' => 'CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget', 'fetch' => '2', 'cascade' => array(), 'isCascadeRemove' => false, 'isCascadePersist' => false, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false, 'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false, 'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => array('client_id' => 'id'), 'joinColumnFieldNames' => array('client_id' => 'client_id'), 'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => array('id' => 'client_id'), 'orphanRemoval' => false), '2')
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 687  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeChangeSet (object(ClassMetadata), object(Budget))
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 404  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeScheduleInsertsChangeSets ()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 711  +
at UnitOfWork ->computeChangeSets ()
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 297  +
at UnitOfWork ->commit (null)
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 340  +
at EntityManager ->flush ()
in src/CDG/PanelBundle/Controller/BudgetController.php at line 36  +
at BudgetController ->addAction (object(Request))
at call_user_func_array (array(object(BudgetController), 'addAction'),   array(object(Request)))
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3109  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3071  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3222  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2444  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in web/app_dev.php at line 28  +
```

It doesn't mean anything to me. I don't know what to do. Other's solutions did not help me at all. If you need any more code please ask me and I will edit it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use annotations in your entities and that you start using the formbuilder. Also add a __toString() method to the Client Entity!

**Your Entities:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    // YOUR OTHER CLIENT FIELDS

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Budget", mappedBy="client")
     **/
    private $budgets;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->budgets = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /* this function is required to present the entity as a string */
    public function __toString() {
         return $this->name;
    }

}
```

and second:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Budget
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Budget
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // YOUR BUDGET FIELDS

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="budgets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $client;

}
```

Then put following commands in the console from your projects main directory:
(maybe you have to enter the word **php** before every command)

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
app/console doctrine:generate:crud AppBundle:Client
( type YES by the question Do you want to generate the "write" actions [no]?)
app/console doctrine:generate:crud AppBundle:Budget
( type YES by the question Do you want to generate the "write" actions [no]?)
```

and take a look to the new routes:

```
app/console router:debug
```

As you can see you can browse to

***web/app_dev.php/client/*** and to

***web/app_dev.php/budget/*** and take a look!

Then open ../src/AppBundle/Form/BudgetType.php in your editor and you will find this rule:

```
    $builder
        ->add('client')
    ;
```

this is where the client property is added to the form. Symfony sets this form field automatically to the [entity formtype](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html). You can write this also like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('client', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Client',
        'empty_value' => '',
    ))
;
```

So now you can choose your Client in the Budget form.

As you may have noticed the commands added also a ClientController and a BudgetController for you.
For more information about [formtypes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) see the documentation.

Comment: Just adding the `entity` field type in my `BudgetType` and `__toString()` method in my Client entity solved this problem. I didn't need to do anything else, like new routes and new Bundle whatsoever, that would break my project's structure. For your suggestion: I rather use YAML instead of annotations because for me the code looks more organized, even if I have to write few more. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that you could solve it. Still have to say that you should use the formbuilder. Its the best there is to generate forms.

Comment: what is this formbuilder you say? Generated automatically or something else? The way Doctrine generates the forms and stuff are truly ugly and messy. I think it is important to understand what is happening before generating everything. It's good to face issues like this, and even better to have people willing to write huge solutions for you. Thank you again. :)

Comment: This formbuilders generates nice forms for you if you get common to the possibilities. I agree if you say that you must understand what is happening but Symfony's formbuilder (not Doctrine) is really a 'must learn'.  Starting here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html